# Adding a plastic cover over teeth (braces)

Tags: modeling

I have model of teeth. I need to make a plastic like cover over it as shown in image below. Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There's a chance that the clearcoat option of the principled shader will do the trick. You can set it to > 1 if you type in the value manually.

Comment: Okay, I will try that also. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Teeth plastic braces

In short - Solidify, Remesh, Boolean modifier

[image]

I used model from [Blendswap](https://www.blendswap.com/blend/14222). Teeths on this model are open on bottom part. For remeshing is necessary close the mesh topology (make manifold). Go to edit mode, select all and press *Fill* (F). Same for *Gum* object, just here is better to use *Grid Fill*.

Add modifiers

- **Solidify** desired thickness
- **Remesh** > *Voxel* > *Size* 0.01
- **Boolean** > *Difference* > *Object* "Gum" (decrease *Threshold* 0 m)

Copy Object (just for safety) and *Apply* modifiers (cmd+A)

Because bottom part is after boolean operation filled, go to edit mode search for **Sharp Edges** > increase to 75 deg, press (V) **Split**, select one bottom face and press (L) **Linked**, (X) **Delete**
(or you can use *Edge Split* modifier for the same purpose)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Note:

- I tried to make smooth transition between teeth, but you can make it more sharpen if you use *Solidify* only for the final result (so skip first *Solidify* and start directly with *Remesh* modifier).
- Solidify used only at the end prevent brace to overlap gum as visible on the first image now, or use Solidify for Boolean operation on Gum object as well.
- To select bottom part with *Sharp Edge* is a magic in this case :) Previously I spent several hours by selecting bottom part with Select Similar Co-planar that seemed to be fine but there left a lot of small parts around edge that raised as a lot of issues after Solidify on final mesh.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.The cover here is the same that we use in real time to straighten teeth. But can you please elaborate more on adding plane. Did you just add in in the object or used a boolean?

Comment: And also can you share settings of solidify modifier.